# What is the maximum markers quantity in the Leaflet library on a standard browser?

Tags: javascript, performance, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using Leaflet on standard conditions, let's say Firefox on a usual PC.
What is the maximum markers quantity it can display at the same time?

I don't need an exact number, just to know capabilities, is near the 1000 dots, near 10.000 or can it display 100k without problems?

Comment: I've shown 100,000+ markers, but using the `L.MarkerCluster` plugin to do so - Chrome may use up to 2GB-3GB or more to handle that many markers, however, and scrolling/zooming (redrawing) the map can get sluggish. When using clusters I wouldn't recommend more than 50K markers, in general, and even that is a bit high in my opinion. For non clustered markers 4K seems to be OK. This site does it well: limits to 4K features, uses level of detail polygons, etc., to fake it: https://tree-map.nycgovparks.org/

Comment: Crap, nevermind about the NYC trees map - it used to use Leaflet, but now uses MapBoxGl.. probably because of the limitations of using Leaflet. Vector tiles probably the way to go for very large data sets

Answer (score 7):

I guess the border is something like 1000 as it's getting hard for browsers to deal with huge amount of smal object instances. For example, if you load hundrets of point objects from a KML it's getting pretty slow at every JS webmap framework.

A better way to deal with that problem is to use server side components to filter the objects. For example stream simplified layers for low zoomlevels and just stream the nessary objects within your current map view via a bbox filter strategy.

Comment: thanks for answer MaM, but I've already using leaflet on 1700 dots without any lags, and even more most of them are connected with lines. I'm going to enlarge it until 10k, but don't know the limits.

Comment: There is no fixed limit that works for everyone. Mobile devices and old computers may already have problems with 1000 markers while faster computers will handle more.

Comment: @pan1ka, if you already tested with up to 1.7K markers you should have mentioned that in your question. I find it rather weird that you ask if the limit is 1K when you already know it isn't.

Comment: @iH8, sorry for that, but 1) my PC is with better configuraton than standart and 2) I thought maybe each of us have tested it and have different results.

Comment: @scai thanks for editing my mistakes in english and for answer.

Comment: As perspective I would like to suggest the server based approach, as it improves the scalability signficant :-)